# can i simply delete local git clone directories without problems? (tortoisegit/bitbucket)

Tags: bitbucket, tortoisegit, git-clone

i'm experimenting with tortoisegit and bitbucket. new to both.

from one repo, i created two local clones in separate directories - one to test cloning, the second one 'for real', for a visual studio website.

i don't need the first test-clone now, so can i simply delete the local, cloned directories without problems or should i be using a specific tortoisegit command? i'm thinking maybe the server/master repo is keeping track of the clones or something like that and so i should "tell it" that i'm deleting one. i don't know if that's necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To delete a cloned repository all you need to do is to delete the whole directory.

No commands need to be run to delete the clone from bitbucket.

Comment: no need to worry about the server then? there's no "connection," so to speak?

Comment: No, there's no connection back to the server when you need to delete a git repostiry. I think the long explanation lies in the fact that git is fully distributed. You'll get a full copy of the repository on clone.  The git server, bitbucket your case doesn't do much apart from being a git repository itself.